# Spring Data: query by example using setter accessor

Tags: mongodb, javafx, spring-data

I have a class that contains javafx StringProperty (and SimpleStringProperty).

My MongoRepository correctly stores objects and class types.

Retrieval via query by example throws the following Exception:
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot set immutable property javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty.name!

Can Spring Data and/or MongoRepository be configured to use setter methods, rather than trying to set the property directly?

Comment: Can you edit the question to include some code or a [mcve]?

Comment: You may wish to adapt an [MVVM architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model–view–viewmodel) where the JavaFX properties are the View-Model and the Model is plain Java classes or DAOs targeted at SpringData/MongoDB and not JavaFX.  But there may be a way of handling this directly without an architecture update (I'm not familiar enough with SpringData/MongoDB to say).  Even if there is a way to do it without an architecture update, you may wish to update the architecture anyway.

Comment: I don't know Mongo; using SpringData with JPA you can specify that entities use "property access" rather than "field access"; i.e. this means they'd operate on the entities via get/set methods instead of reflectively setting the variable. There's likely to be something similar.